# zpool fails to import raidz3 pool despite sufficient replicas available

Tags: zfs, ubuntu-18.04, zfsonlinux

Some users were having issues connecting to this server's share on the pool, while other's who were already on seemed to be fine. After arranging a reboot the pool failed to import once the system booted.

During the reboot I noticed a drive faulted during POST, indicated by an orange light on the bezel, and below in `zpool import`.

The pool has enough devices to be brought online, but it won't successfully import.

```
$ zpool import
   pool: darkpool
     id: 5743344949875332602
  state: DEGRADED
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool can be imported despite missing or damaged devices.  The
    fault tolerance of the pool may be compromised if imported.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
 config:

    darkpool                      DEGRADED
      raidz3-0                    DEGRADED
        wwn-0x5000c5008581aafb    ONLINE
        wwn-0x5000c5008581b61b    ONLINE
        wwn-0x5000c5008581b79f    ONLINE
        wwn-0x5000c5008581b933    ONLINE
        wwn-0x5000c5008581b953    ONLINE
        wwn-0x5000c5008581bdf7    ONLINE
        wwn-0x5000c50085825ec7    ONLINE
        wwn-0x5000c5008581cc03    ONLINE
        wwn-0x5000c5008581e423    UNAVAIL
        wwn-0x5000c5008581fd3f    ONLINE
        wwn-0x5000c50085820b93    ONLINE
        wwn-0x5000c500858211b3    ONLINE
        wwn-0x5000cca267ab0de4    ONLINE
        spare-13                  DEGRADED
          11992420879588183985    FAULTED  corrupted data
          wwn-0x5000c500858252ef  ONLINE
    spares
      wwn-0x5000c500858252ef

$ zpool status
no pools available

$ zpool import darkpool
cannot import 'darkpool': I/O error
    Destroy and re-create the pool from
    a backup source.

$ zpool import -f darkpool
cannot import 'darkpool': I/O error
    Destroy and re-create the pool from
    a backup source.

$ zpool import -fFn darkpool

$ zpool import -F darkpool
cannot import 'darkpool': I/O error
    Destroy and re-create the pool from
    a backup source.

$ zpool import -fFX darkpool
cannot import 'darkpool': I/O error
    Destroy and re-create the pool from
    a backup source.
```

Has anyone seen something like this before? I'm not sure what to try before destroying the pool and restoring from a backup (I'd like to avoid this since it will take so long).

It looks like the backups started to fail a couple of weeks ago. Is there any way to know if having the faulted drive serviced would make the pool happy?

The system is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with zfsutils-linux_0.7.5-1ubuntu16.7_amd64.

Comment: This looks awfully similar:  https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/8684, even down to the version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Interesting, I wonder if it's a bug. I'll try to see if he ever resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up signing up for LinkedIn Premium so I could message a ZFS developer (who was actually kind enough to respond!). He suggested I move the pool to a system with ZFS 0.8, a version which his relevant commits on Github were included in Ububtu 19.10, among others distros.

**In read-only mode**, we were able to load the pool by disabling the option `spa_load_verify_metadata`. This also skips the scan of the pool so you don't have to wait minutes or hours depending on the size of your pool.

Once the pool was loaded I started a backup of everything to a different server, with plans to destroy the pool and server (too many on-site trips from Dell, replacing CPUs, memory, the mobo, etc...), and start fresh with a new system.

---

## Toggling the Option (Ubuntu 19.10):

```
$ cat /sys/module/zfs/parameters/spa_load_verify_metadata
1
$ echo 0 >/sys/module/zfs/parameters/spa_load_verify_metadata
$ cat /sys/module/zfs/parameters/spa_load_verify_metadata
0
```

## Loading the Pool

```
zpool import -o readonly=on darkpool -f
```

The flag will reset after a reboot, so the pool won't load during the boot process. But really you want to copy the data and stop using the pool anyway.